# Ayuda Error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"

Tags: python

Soy principiante en python y no se porque me sale este error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` trate de seguir otras problemas parecidos usando el `int()` también el `float()` pero me sigue dando el mismo error acá esta mi código

```
#Calcula la distancia de 2 puntos en un plano cartesiano
print ("Calcular la distancia de 2 puntos en el plano cartesiano")
#Obtencion de datos
xypnt1 =input("Ingrese un numero para el eje X y Y respectivamente del punto A ej: 2,4: ")
xypnt2 =input("Ingrese un numero para el eje X y Y respectivamente del punto B ej: 2,4: ")
#Presentacion de Datos
print ("Las cordenadas del punto A son: "+"("+str(xypnt1)+")")
print ("Las cordenadas del punto B son: "+"("+str(xypnt2)+")")
#Calculamos la distancia
dis = (xypnt1-xypnt2)
#Muestra de resultados
print ("La distancia entre el punto A y el punto B es: "+str(dis))
```

Me ayudarían mucho como puedo arreglarlo gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define las siguientes funciones:

```
def convert_to_point(strpoint):
  [x, y] = list(map(float, strpoint.split(',')))
  return x, y

def sustract(x1, y1, x2, y2):
  return x1 - x2, y1 - y2
```

Luego en tu codigo reemplaza por esto:

```
#Calculamos la distancia
x1, y1 = convert_to_point(xypnt1)
x2, y2 = convert_to_point(xypnt2)

dis = sustract(x1, y1, x2, y2)
#Muestra de resultados
print ("La distancia entre el punto A y el punto B es: "+str(dis))
```

Ve si te sirve, saludos